# Docker: deploying a new version of an app that uses external resources

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am developping an app that uses a database : I have prepared an image for the app and created a docker-compose file containing the image of the app, the image of the database and a volume for the data to be used by the image of the database.

For the first deployment everything will be fine, but how could I deploy a new version of the application and continuing using the existing image of the database and the existing data volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest solution here would be to `git pull` your latest changes and run

`docker-compose up --no-deps --force-recreate app-service-name`